# ASP.Net - Cannot open database "Database Name" requested by the login

Tags: sql-server-express

I'm working on a website in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition(x64) on a Windows 7 Home Premium(x64) laptop.
After Debugging i am getting an error-

```
Cannot open database "Edufun.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.
```

Edufun is my database name. I have tried various solution like setting up a login via SQL Server management studio, making NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE db_owner of my database. Changed my connection string various times by various methods. Also given Read and Write Permission to Network Service to the database. My connection string is same in IIS and WEB.Config.

I have seen various solution but nothing worked my connection string is =

```
name="connection" "Server=RUSTY\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Edufun.mdf;
Integrated Security=true"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Rusty is my PC name an during SQL Server installation i had created default instance by the name SQLExpress.
please help me out with this if anybody need the stack trace tell me  i will post it.
thank You in Advance

Comment: Try this without mdf extension - `Database=Edufun;`

Comment: Did you enable Impersonation on your web server? Since you are using integrated security, you might need it.

Comment: Thanx for your response
on enabling the asp.net impersonation on debug it gives an error dialog box saying "unable to start debugging on web server, see help for common configuration error. verify that there is no syntax error in web.config"

Comment: removing .mdf extension doesn't help

Comment: I have solved this error of impersonation by changing the app pool from v4.0 to classic but still no luck. The bloody error comes again Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'

Comment: Post your whole web.config, there might be an error in it.

Comment: My web.config file

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yFXOawK6dHwg-YASNQ8jt6-kJ1NUPJ4yna52hdFw8RE/edit